# opening sdcard directory and showing it on screen

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have a query. I need to show all the contents of sdcard specific folder. What I need to do is I need to tell the user that there are no files in a particular directory in sdcard so need to open that folder and show it on screen. For eg. I there is no internet we can show an alert to open internet and also open the settings screen. Same way I also want to open the sdcard/myFolder screen. Please guide me what to do if its possible in android? 
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code to check if the directory is available and have files:

```
String Directory = "";
String[] mFileList ;
//GET ROOT DIRECTORY OF EXTERNAL STORAGE + DIRECTORY THAT YOU WANT

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + DIRECTORY);
if(dir.exists()) {
  mFileList = dir.list(filter);   
  if(mFileList.length==0)
    //Inform that directory is empty
}
else {
  //Inform user that there is no such directory
}
```

Then you can open dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = null;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo));//this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
builder.setTitle("Choose your file");
if(mFileList == null) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "Showing file picker before loading the file list");
    dialog = builder.create();
}
builder.setItems(mFileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mChosenFile = mFileList[which];
        //Do something after choosing the file
    }
});    

dialog = builder.show();
return true;
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Marek did the same . Can you please tell me what does the dialog below does?

Comment: This dialog displays all the files in a particular folder. If returns a filename that you choose. You can use this filename afterwards.